# How do you make a list view clickable

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to get this right, but this is getting me good. I have an example but i don't know  how it is working.

I got this much done.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/welcome" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now I think my problem is in this java file. The getListView thing is kicking me around. I think this is the answer but i just don't know how to get this right. 
I think i know how to get it to work later.

```
    package com.example.boonehallfrightnightsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final String[] CHOICES = new String[]
            {
                "Main House",
                "Nightmare",
                "Zombie Town",
                "Hayride",
                "Quit"
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //found this part on an example
         //Set up ArrayAdaptor for the options
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CHOICES));
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }

    private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


     private void setListClickListener()
        {
            //Set up the click listener for the options
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener
            (
                new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    //@Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                    {
                        switch(arg2)
                        {
                            case 0: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 1: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 2: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 3: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 4: finish();
                                    break;
                            default: break;
                        }
                    }
                }//END OnItemClickListener
            );//END setOnItemClickListener
        }//END setListClickListener

}
```

Comment: Check `MainActivity extends ListActivity`

Comment: Got that but now it won't show up when i run it.... odd.

Comment: found out the problem. I had an auto gen methhead lol. works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend `ListActivity` to call `getListView()` to get the ListView from the layout. You can check the documentation here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html (Class Overview > Screen Layout)